# How to hide the on-screen keyboard when pressed enter/pressed one of google places predictions?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, google-places, on-screen-keyboard

I've created an Android app that uses the Google Places AutoCompleteTextView which successfully lists the predictions. However, when a user has selected the prediction that they are looking for, the keyboard doesn't hide (Same for when a user presses enter or finish on the keyboard). How easy is to to hide the keyboard once a user has selected one of the Google predictions?

Comment: Strange, as my AutocCompleteTextViews usually close the keyboard upon selection. I guess you can do a myTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener( //do stuff to close keyboard).

Comment: Hmm... Well... This is what I currently have. There may be an issue with they way that I implemented it or something: http://pastebin.com/44QBuKXd

Answer (score 1):

@DERPA_CHIEF You were correct!
The code necessary to add was:

```
autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                  InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                  mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(autoCompView.getWindowToken(), 0);
              }
            });
```